# При сворачивании игры кадр который ставится в миниPreview

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, activity-life-cycle

Не знаю как это назвать. Когда открываешь свернутую игру в списке запущенных программ, то на каждом окне стоит кадр, который был последним при сворачивании игры. Так вот, в каком месте происходит выбор этого кадра? Потому что когда я сворачиваю, я вижу последний кадр, а на фон ставится предпоследний.

Разница в каждом кадре большая и когда я прерываю поток, то иногда сохраняется для превью последний кадр, а иногда предпоследний. Вот интересно, какой же метод этим занимается, чтобы немножко править его. Рисую используя интерфейс SurfaceHolder.Callback на Канве.

Исходя из сделанной мне подсказки написал вот такое:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail(Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) {
    super.onCreateThumbnail(outBitmap, canvas);
    outBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.face_box);
    canvas.drawBitmap(outBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
    Log.d(TAG,"Скрин");
    return  true;
}
```

Но при сворачивании приложения в лог не выводится Log.d(TAG,"Скрин"); значит метод почему то не запускается.

Вот тут написано, что этот метод никогда не запускается. Кому-то требуется, чтобы этот скрин в таскменеджере не показывал, например, переписку или еще что-либо. Как же это реализовать. Знаю есть приложения, ставящие пароль на любое приложение, и, даже открыв это приложение в таскменеджере, мы увидим не скрин с самого приложения, а изображение, выставленное приложением-блокиратором.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам надо переопределить метод в вашем `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail (Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) {
    //blah-blah
}
```

Именно этот метод отвечает за скриншот, который попадает в таск менеджер. Вам надо переопределить этот метод и залить туда то что вы хотите.

Документация [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas)

Comment: Вы меня правильно поняли, это то что нужно , только где использовать его? в  class Menu extends AppCompatActivity  я его не могу прописать так как метода такого нет .  всякие onStop() переопределяются, а этого метода почему то нет..

Comment: вот ....  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370   Тут написано о том что onCreateThumbnail никогда не будет вызываться, какие то проблемы OC.

Comment: Там речь идет об ICS, думаю в новых версиях проблема решена

Comment: ну на андроид 5.1 и на эмуляторе андроид 6 не решена я проверил, а на форуме в  конце человек пишет что на андроид 7.1 не решена, 5 лет прошло с появления этой проблемы